# The local chart of the embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a $m$-dimensional smooth manifolds with boundary. $N$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ such that $\partial N = \partial M \cap N$ and $N$ is transverse to $\partial M$, that is, for any $x \in \partial N$, ${T_x}N + {T_x}\partial M = {T_x}M$. Then for any $p \in \partial N$, can we find a chart $(\varphi ,U)$ around $p$ such that $\varphi :U \to V \subseteq \mathbb H^n$ is a diffeomorphism from $U$ to an open set $V$ of the upperplane $\mathbb H^n$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\varphi (U \cap N) = \{ x \in V|{x_1} = {x_2} =  \cdots  = {x_{m - n}} = 0\} $

Comment: Do you have access to Kosinski's "Differential Manifolds"? If so you should look at 2.8.2 in section 2 of chapter 2.

Comment: @Timkinsella Thanks.